# How to display a CommandButton upon selecting a specific picklist value?

Tags: apex, visualforce

What I need help with is for the pageblock which has command buttons to display only when the condition is met (I.E when user selects `<apex:selectOption itemLabel="Course Modification Request" itemValue="F_Course_Modification_Request"></apex:selectOption>` as the Request type)

Controller Code:

```
    Public without sharing class  TDR_Learning_Request_ctrl extends SitesController
    {
        public boolean show{get;set;}
        public boolean hide{get;set;}
        public Boolean abool {get;set;}
        public Boolean bbool {get;set;}
        public Boolean sabool {get;set;}
        public Boolean sbbool {get;set;}
        public Boolean habool {get;set;}
        public Boolean hbbool {get;set;}
        public Boolean sabbool {get;set;}
        public Boolean habbool {get;set;}

        Public TDR_Learning_Request_ctrl(){

            //Creating record 
            ocaseformextn = new Case_form_Extn__c ();
            caseformmap =  new Map<string,Case_form_Extn__c> ();
            Ocase = new case();



         requestTypeOptions = new List<selectoption>();     
           requestTypeOptions.add(new selectoption('Attestations','Attestations'));
           requestTypeOptions.add(new selectoption('Course Modification      Request','F_Course_Modification_Request'));          

            ShowModification=false;
            abool = false;
            bbool = false;
            sabbool = true;
            sabool = true;
            sbbool = true;

         }

    //Methods to display pageblocks which has fields,those need to be displayed upon button click
         public void showBlickA()
             {
            abool = true;
            check();
             }

        public void showBlockB()
           {
            bbool = true;
            check();
           } 

           public void check()
        {
            if(abool == true && bbool == false)
            {
                sabool = false;
                sbbool = true;
                habool = true;
                hbbool = false;
                sabbool = true;
                habbool = false;
            }
            else if(abool == false && bbool == true)
            {
                sabool = true;
                sbbool = false;
                habool = false;
                hbbool = true;
                sabbool = true;
                habbool = false;
            }

         }

        //Only the block which has commandbuttons (ShowA,ShowB) to be displayed upon    //condition met like below
          public PageReference requestTypeOnChange(){

         if(ocaseformextn.TDR_Request_Type__c=='F_Course_Modification_Request' ){

                  showModification= true;
                }else {
                   showModification= false;
                }               

    }




}
```

VF Code:

```
<apex:actionRegion >
<apex:selectList label="Request Type" value="{!ocaseformextn.TDR_Request_Type__c}" size="1" multiselect="false" id="selection">
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!requestTypeOnChange}" reRender="fieldSet,attachid,downloadId,ModifyCoursePanelId,ModifyClassPanelId"/>                          
<apex:actionstatus startText="Applying Values............."> </apex:actionstatus>                  

<apex:selectOption itemLabel="" itemValue=""></apex:selectOption>
<apex:selectOption itemLabel="Attestations" itemValue="Attestations"></apex:selectOption>

<apex:selectOption itemLabel="Course Modification Request" itemValue="F_Course_Modification_Request"></apex:selectOption>                                                                                                            </apex:selectList>
</apex:actionRegion>

<!--This is the block that i want to display which has commandbuttons upon condition met in the controller i.e if(ocaseformextn.TDR_Request_Type__c=='F_Course_Modification_Request' )----> 

<apex:pageBlock title="Modify Another Item" rendered="{showModification}">
<apex:commandButton value="Show A" action="{!showA}" rendered="{!sabool}" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<apex:commandButton value="Show B" action="{!showB}" rendered="{!sbbool}" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</apex:pageBlock>

     i am good with the below part:

<!---below two blocks have the fields that i want to display upon click of the commandbuttons in the above pageblock---->

    <apex:pageBlock title="Block A" rendered="{!abool}">
    <Apex:OutputLabel >Modification Type</Apex:OutputLabel> 
    <apex:inputfield value="{!ocaseformextn.Modification_Type33__c}" />
    <Apex:OutputLabel >Description</Apex:OutputLabel> 
    <apex:inputfield value="{!ocaseformextn.Description_1__c}" />
        This is Block A.<br/><br/>        
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Block B" rendered="{!bbool}">
    <Apex:OutputLabel >Modification Type</Apex:OutputLabel> 
    <apex:inputfield value="{!ocaseformextn.Modification_Type333__c}" />
    <Apex:OutputLabel >Description</Apex:OutputLabel> 
    <apex:inputfield value="{!ocaseformextn.Description_11__c}" /> 
        This is Block B.<br/><br/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question to my best,please have a look.

Comment: You still haven't shown us what you tried, only what you want to do. I would ask you to show us some code you've tried and we can help you fix it.

Comment: @user27686 pls correct me if I am wrong. So what I understood.. you need onclick of `Show A` button `Block A` should display and onclick of `Show B` button `Block B` should display. correct?

Comment: @user27686 it is not matter if it is in same pageblock or different.. Can you pls update your qus and let me know what is the exact issue you are facing

Comment: Hi Ratan, Exatcly that is what i want and it is happeing,but those two buttons are in one pageblock
 which is initially showing up on my page ,but i want that pageblock to be displayed upon selecting only a particular selectoption 
  I.e.. 
<apex:selectOption itemLabel="Course Modification Request" itemValue="F_Course_Modification_Request"></apex:selectOption>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a button on screen when a specific value is selected, you just need:

- a variable to hold the value you selected;
- a `rerender` attribute to specify that your button needs to be rerendered once value is changed;
- a `rendered` condition to handle rendering;

Your code would look a little like this (there might be some missing tags in this example):

```
<apex:selectlist value="{!myvariable}">
    <apex:selectoptions value="{!options}"></apex:selectoptions>
    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" rerender="mybutton"></apex:actionsupport>
</apex:selectlist>
<apex:commandButton id="mybutton" value="Click me!" action="{!executeAction}" rendered="{!myvariable == 'renderthebutton'}"></apex:commandButton>
```

When the user changes the value on the `selectlist`, the `actionSupport` will trigger a rerender on the button, which will evaluate the `rendered` expression and render it on the screen or not.